# Cocoa bindings not reading a nil value from user defaults

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have two UI components whose values are synchronized through user defaults. The first one is essentially an input field, the other a menu item. When the value of the input field changes, the key equivalent of the menu item changes through Cocoa bindings:

```
Input Field -> NSUserDefaultsController -> User Defaults
User Defaults -> NSUserDefaultsController -> Menu Item
```

This works perfectly for everything but a `nil` value. For some reason I can’t store the actual `nil` value in user defaults, I use an empty dictionary instead. On the other side that reads the value I have a transformer that “inflates” the empty dictionary into a `nil` value.

Now, when I enter a non-nil value into the input field, it gets through to user defaults and is correctly propagated all the way to the menu item. When I enter an “empty” value, an empty dictionary is correctly stored in the user defaults, but the bound value of the menu item does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did wrong was implementing the binding on the menu item as a hack. I introduced a `keyCombo` property through a category:

```
@interface NSMenuItem (Combo)
@property(assign, nonatomic) MASShortcut *keyCombo;
@end
```

This is the property that gets bound to user defaults. Then, since I couldn’t easily add an instance variable in a category, I simply returned `nil` in the getter:

```
@implementation NSMenuItem (Combo)

- (MASShortcut*) keyCombo
{
    return nil;
}

/* setter omitted */

@end
```

This worked well until I wanted to set the property to `nil` through bindings. Because the getter was always returning `nil`, the Cocoa bindings machinery thought there was no need to update the property value, as it seemed to be `nil` already.